# Parsing a file with several conditions

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, ksh

i want to create a script to parse a file. These are what i need to do;

1. I want to take the first line only of every app. I want to check only columns 1,3,4. If an app has more than Instance i want only first one. For exp. THSMOB11 will be picked but THSMOB12 will be commented. THSINT11 picked THSINT12 commented.
2. I want to add "#" in front of the other lines that i don't want to use.

Example Text

```
App Name                        Channel     Folder      Instance
ThisServicesBusiness            This        Thisbcr1    THSMOB11
ThisServicesBusiness            This        Thisbin1    THSINT11
ThisServicesBusiness            This        Thisbbr1    THSBRC11
ThisServicesBusiness            This        Thisbot1    THSIVR11
ThisServicesBusiness            This        Thisadm1    THSWS11 
ThisServicesBusiness            This        Thisbcr1    THSMOB12
ThisServicesBusiness            This        Thisbin1    THSINT12
ThisServicesBusiness            This        Thisbbr1    THSBRC12
ThisServicesBusiness            This        Thisbbr1    THSBRC13
```

I started with this code.

```
#!/bin/ksh

while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    echo "Text read from file: $line"
done < "$1"
```

Expected Result;

```
ThisServicesBusiness            This        Thisbcr1    THSMOB11
ThisServicesBusiness            This        Thisbin1    THSINT11
ThisServicesBusiness            This        Thisbbr1    THSBRC11
ThisServicesBusiness            This        Thisbot1    THSIVR11
ThisServicesBusiness            This        Thisadm1    THSWS11 
#ThisServicesBusiness           This        Thisbcr1    THSMOB12
#ThisServicesBusiness           This        Thisbin1    THSINT12
#ThisServicesBusiness           This        Thisbbr1    THSBRC12
#ThisServicesBusiness           This        Thisbbr1    THSBRC13
```

Comment: post the expected result

Comment: After all the edits, there are no bold lines. Is $3 the key?

Comment: I just made another edit and made it clear. Thanks for warning.

Answer (score 3):

**`Awk`** suits much better for such case:

```
awk 'a[$1]++{ $0="#"$0 }1' file
```

- `a[$1]++{ $0="#"$0 }` - associative array `a` will hold the number of occurrences for each *"app name"* (presented by the 1st field `$1`) using *"app name"* as array key. Starting from the 2nd occurrence the whole record `$0` will be prepended with `#` char

---

The output:

```
App1 Channel1 Name1 Folder1
#App1 Channel1 Name2 Folder1
App2 Channel1 Name1 Folder1
#App2 Channel1 Name1 Folder1
App3 Channel1 Name1 Folder1
App4 Channel1 Name1 Folder1
#App1 Channel2 Name1 Folder1
#App1 Channel3 Name1 Folder1
#App1 Channel1 Name1 Folder2
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the detailed answer and it works nice. But, is it possible to write a code with while and if? Thanks.

Comment: @HüseyinErkmen, see [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716)

Comment: Thanks much. I am new on shell and learning is awesome. Thanks friends.